# Why are imported packages visible inside other packages?

Tags: python, package

If I create a package named `foo` that imports `bar`, why is `bar` visible under `foo` as `foo.bar` when I import `foo` in another module? Is there a way to prevent this; to keep `bar` hidden so as not to clutter the namespace?

Comment: Import bar directly into the other module

Comment: How would that prevent `foo.bar` from being visible? And in any event, `foo` still requires `bar` so I can't just eliminate the `import`.

Comment: [Relevant SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024049/is-it-pythonic-to-import-inside-functions)

Comment: Is there anything that is invisible in python? I think it's the philosophy of the programming language not to hide things..

Comment: @Alex `private`/`protected`??

Comment: @rjv private members in python are private by convention not by implementation. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private

Comment: As far as I know, the conventional way to solve this problem is to package the code into a module, and to use `__init__.py` files to control what is imported. Within the `__init__.py` files, you either import submodules with their own `__init__.py` files, creating a subnamespace, or you do `from file.py import *`. Within `file.py`, you then declare what is exported with `__all__ = [ 'symbolname1', 'symbolname2', ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Import bar wherever you use it, rather than globally

If bar is being used in a function, import as

```
def func():
  import bar
  ....
```

Or even,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import bar
    my_main(bar)
```

Or if you love `class`es,

```
class Fubar():
    def __init__(self):
        import bar
        self.bar = bar
```

Comment: Will importing bar every time func is called harm performance? [It seems so.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462935/does-importing-more-slow-down-scripts-python)

Comment: It will, you can consider setting the bar as instance of a class and use it, if you use classes

Comment: @Emre Time it. Here, `python -m timeit 'import sys' 'sys.argv[1]'` needs `1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.965 usec per loop`, while `python -m timeit '' 'import sys; sys.argv[1]'` needs `1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.957 usec per loop`. So it's essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

Imports in Python are really just another form of name assignment. There is really no difference between an object that has been imported into foo and one that has been defined in foo - they are both visible internally and externally in exactly the same way. So no, there is no way to prevent this.

I don't really see how this is cluttering the namespace, though. You've still only imported one name, foo, into your other module.

Comment: If you import a long list of packages, it can crowd out the ones you actually want to expose when you do command completion. It's pollution from the user's perspective.

Comment: But you're not importing a list, you're just importing foo. The modules imported inside foo shouldn't affect autocompletion, surely.

Comment: I meant to say there are packages besides foo that are similarly imported. Autocomplete does indeed see and suggest bar.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR: Python Imports create named bindings for pieces of code so they can be referenced and used.**

An import is essentially binding a piece of code to a name. So the namespace should always reflect what has been imported. If you hide that you may end up causing unexpected problems for someone else or yourself.

If you are importing the wrong modules, importing modules you don't use, or have a ton of imports because you have 10 classes in one file you should consider fixing the underlying issue(s).  Not trying to hide it by messing with how modules are imported.